# Facebook API - Retrieve Posts and Comments in Private Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I have created many apps that collect group posts and comments in the past.  I have created the new app and I am able to login and get credentials.  When I try to collect the information for the private group I receive a blank return.

I am using the administrators account but it does not make a difference which account I use.

I have been digging through the documentation but cant seem to find any details on working with private groups.

Has anyone worked with private groups or know the workaround?

Comment: You need to be admin of the group and you need to have granted user_managed_groups permission to the app

Comment: Ok so I have to setup facebook approval for user_managed_groups.  Assuming they approve my app,  I would then be able to access my group as usaual?

Comment: No they don't have to approve your app. You just need to grant your app that permission

Comment: No according to the documentation and facebook you have to now be approved to use user_managed_groups.

Comment: if you could reply with an answer I will mark yours as the correct one

Comment: You only need to get it reviewed, if you want the app to be used by the general public. Any user with a role in the app can be asked for any permission any time, reviewed or not.